# jquery mobile create page via jsonp

Tags: navigation, jsonp, jquery-mobile

so I have jQueryMobile app I'm working on and what I want to do is when the user clicks a link I want it to go get JSONP data from mysites api then have the success of the jsonp call create the content in the current moble app page now when the initial page loads I can call the jsonp and fill the page but when I click a link i get error message saying "error loading page" so how do i set it up to when user clicks a link it triggers the jsonp call that will create the content for display by jquery mobile?

**EDIT**

trying to explain better

I have an intial page setup

*html*

```html
<div data-role="page" class='maninpage' id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-scroll="x">
        <div>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/iphoneheader.gif" alt="Penn State Live"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="colleges">Colleges</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="campuswires">Campuses</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="facultystaff">Faculty and Staff</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ofinterest">Of Interest</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="photos">Photos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="videos">Video</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="subscriptions">Newswire Subscription</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="psutxt">PSUTXT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="footer"></div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

then on startup I call this function giving start params

```js
get_jsonp(data)

function get_jsonp(data){
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data:data,
    jsonpCallback:'create_content',
    async:false,
    url:'myapi'
 });
}
```

In my create_content callback it creates an html list which I then use to populate the ul

like this

```js
$('#content').empty().append(content);
$("div#content ul").listview();
```

So then when someone clicks a link I want it to repeat the process with the new parameters extracted from the link  sending them to a new traceable page but fill using ajax.

That said I am need to have my callback build a whole new page and that's is fine if thats what I ahave to do but who knows maybe I'm doing this all wrong but I would think that there would be some way to provide content to jquery mobile without returning html ?

Comment: are you trying to refresh the list via ajax?

Comment: pretty much but need to to keep track of where they have come from and have good clean urls, I'd be find with changing the whole page ajax too so long as I can build the pages in my ajax callback as the jsop does not respond with html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/methods.html) you're looking for as you want to use the changePage()

Example:

```
$("[name=button_name]").click(function() { 
    $.mobile.changePage('anotherPage.php?parm=123','slide',false,true);
});
```

so if the user clicks the button (button_name) it will call the 'anotherPage.php?parm=123' page, (slide) is the transition type, (false) is the reverse direction transition type and (true) is if you want to keep track of the page

UPDATED (from your comments)

Not sure but you might try this

```
$.mobile.changePage({
    // this posts to the page anotherPage.php, 
    // you could capture these parms and do some action
    url: 'anotherPage.php?parm=123&another=foobar', 
    type: 'post', 
    // this posts the data from the form to the 
    // same page as above, this could do other actions
    data: $('form#your_form').serialize() 
},'slide',false,false);
```

I would treat the

- url: as the requesting page (what to display)

and the

- data: as the submission data you need.

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the page or change the content? If navigate the code looks good but if reload/refreshing the content you can use the .html() in a ajax call and refresh with .page()

Comment: I am really trying to do both what happens is my api returns json object not html so my return functions creates the html needed so when a person clicks a link it does json call creates the content and updates the url so they can go back  or forward

Comment: no, I don't think I'm explaining this correctly ... I'll try to update post again